# Is it safe to delete the `django_session` table if my Django app is using a cache-based session backend?

Tags: django, django-database, django-sessions

I've enabled [cached-based sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions), and it looks like the application is no longer using the `django_session` database table.

Is it safe to delete it?  Or will the next `migrate` just recreate it?

Should I should just leave it in place, even if it's empty and isn't being used?  Does it even matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I should just leave it in place, even if it's empty and isn't
>   being used? Does it even matter?

You've sort of answered your own question here. Does it even matter? no of course not, an empty table will take up only a few hundred bytes on your disk (for table definition). It's being there will not cause any problems. On the other hand, if you drop it, you will need to recreate it if you ever change your session storage.

> Will the next migrate just recreate it?

The answer here is no. Because the migration table will show that the table was dropped. So you need to recreate manually. While this is not difficult, it's certainly not worth the effort.